# I want to get coordinates of x and y using mouse adapter and insert into an array. But only two values are getting updated every time in whole array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, awt, mouselistener

I want to enter the X and Y coordinates of mouse adapter to array . But whenever I insert them into array using for loop, the whole array is getting filled with same value. How can I insert X and Y coordinates to the array every time the `JPanel` is clicked?

**Code:**

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter () {

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        setBackground(Color.RED);
        int k[]=new int[18];
        int l[]=new int[18];
        for(int i=0;i<=17;i++) {
            k[i]=e.getX();
            l[i]=e.getY();
        }
    }   
});
```

Comment: Hi @SaiTeja, do you really mean to create the k and l arrays on every click event?  And the for loop is setting every element to the values you just got - why don't you add some more explanation of what you are trying to do as the code does exactly what you are complaining about - what is your expected output??

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). One tip I can offer in advance of seeing an MRE / SSCCE, is to use an `ArrayList<Point>` instead of an `int[]`. It has several advantages. 1) It's expandable, so there's no need to guess in advance how many clicks the user will make. 2) There will be only a single datum (the `Point`) to add to it.

Comment: I want to add the coordinate points to array , but whenever i click , the array index is getting reset . I want to insert the x and y coordinates in each index of array whenever I click using mouse adapter . Hope you understand the scenario.

Comment: *"Hope you understand the scenario."* You, who? Tip: Add @MrR (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. I'm guessing you did not mean me, given you've so far failed to provide (MRE / SSCCE) code I suggested posting. Don't wait too long on doing that. This question already has 2 of the 3 close voted needed to .. close it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the OP where the data is meant to be going.  Assuming it's being used elsewhere then -

```java
// NOTE: perhaps use CopyOnWriteArrayList or synchronize all
// use of clicks for MT safety..
final List<Point> clicks = new ArrayList<Point>();
X.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter () {

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        setBackground(Color.RED);
        clicks.add(e.getPoint());
    }   
});
```

Each time the mouse is clicked another point is added to the clicks array.

HT to @AndrewThompson